# How to build two lines aligned maps

Tags: formatting, symbols, positioning

I would like to write a map between two objects, with a map below which specify where any single object is sent. To be more precise. I want to write `$A \rightarrow B$`, and right below it `$\alpha \mapsto \beta$`. I tried with the command `$\underset$` but the maps below gets too smaller, and it's not aligned to the map above. What is the right command?

I apologize if this question has been already asked. To me it looks elementary, nevertheless I couldn't find it nor here nor googling around. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino, Thank you for your suggestion, I'll stick to it for future questions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this or variants like `aligned` if you want it to be part of a larger expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A&\rightarrow B\\
a&\mapsto b
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: rats, ya beat me.  but you might want to mention commutative diagram packages like `xypic` or `tikz` for more complicated diagrams.

Comment: @barbarabeeton and not forgetting `amscd` ?

Comment: `amscd` is intentionally limited.  it only handles strictly horizontal or vertical arrows, so if anything slanted is needed, forget it.  better to start with something more functional.

Answer (score 4):

[`amsmath`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsmath) and [`mathtools`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathtools) offers extensible arrows. (If I get the question correctly)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
A \xrightarrow[\alpha \mapsto \beta]{} B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]